# Writing Non-Standard Characters Into Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, unix, unicode, io, ascii

I've run into a bit of a problem. To do what I'm attempting, I need to be able to enter pure hex values into the standard input of the command line (specifically into a gets() call which is inside of the program) without using IO redirection. I generally have success by using ctrl + u + number to enter ascii characters equivalent to the entered hex value, but I need to be able to enter null chars/backspaces/etc which the terminal either ignores or interprets as an action rather than a character. If I use pipes or IO redirection, I can't interact with the program after the initial input and the program closes. Would anyone have any ideas? I'm thinking possible solutions are either:

1. Find a way to type the characters in manually and have them preserved
2. Find a way to enter the characters in that isn't unicode or ascii but will still be accepted as byte information
3. Find a way to pipe or redirect input to the program that is interpreted as from the command line, and then somehow convince it to give control of input back to the command line immediately

The third one I'm not even sure is possible or useful since I'm not totally sure why the program isn't working if it gets information from anything but the command line directly, all I know is that I have to enter it manually or else it won't run. Would anyone have any ideas for any of those 3 options, or any others you can think of? I'm stumped.

(Oh, also, if anyone can explain why sometimes ctrl+u+number outputs characters with completely different hex values from the entered number, I'm very curious, but I don't think it'll help me with my current problem anyways.)

Comment: "completely different hex values"?

Comment: What I meant was for example, I enter ctrl+u+4748, and if I view that with xxd it has the values of something like c0f9.

Comment: xxd shows the bytes used to encode the character, not the Unicode codepoint.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was a discrepancy between the two. How would I go about creating a character from bytes so that its encoding is what I want, as opposed to its codepoint?

Comment: Generally you don't, since the input method will handle converting it for you.

Comment: So what you're saying is there's no way at all then to enter arbitrary hex values and have them interpreted as unicode?

Comment: Encoded characters are *not* arbitrary hex values.

Comment: No, I realize that, but my hope would be that for every set of arbitrary hex values there is some unicode character which maps to them, and that therefore it would be possible to find a unicode character which maps to my desired hex values.

Comment: Not only is that false, but it also depends on what encoding you're using in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch your `tty` in `raw` (uncooked) mode and then have all typed characters passed to the program without any processing:

```
$ stty raw
$ command ...
$ stty -raw
```

The keyboard is perfectly able to send a null `00` byte with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>, however, <s>there is no way to read it using `gets` which looks to be what you use</s>, make sure you process the string character by character and not as a string as `00` is taken as a terminator in the later case..

`04` is <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in raw mode or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in cooked mode

`05` is <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> but might be intercepted by your terminal emulator in which case you have to disable the shortcut or use another emulator.

`08` is <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in raw mode or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in cooked mode

`74` is simply <kbd>t</kbd>

`84` is not a valid UTF-8 character. You can still pipe this byte it to your program with something like:

```
printf "\204" | command
```

Comment: I'm definitely not well versed in this command so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to do what I want. It works for the very basic command line, but I'm trying to input information into the program which has a gets() call, and with this on I can't ever send a new line to end my input (also, it doesn't help me with entering unprintable characters at all).

Comment: I see, raw mode disable Ctrl-U handling which defeats (at least part of) what you are looking for. About the new lines, you need to enter Control-J as Enter send a Carriage Return which isn't what gets is expecting.

Comment: I just checked and Control-shift-u still works even while in raw mode. You should clarify what characters are causing the issues.

Comment: I guess my problem now is more that, since from the above comments I have learned that ctrl+u+hex value does not neccessarily encode to that hex value, I need to know how to enter characters with the hex values of 00, 05, 04, 08, 74, and 84 from the keyboard. Some of these are common (08 being backspace, 00 being null) but others are not and have no defined shortcut as far as I know. If I had a way to input these characters, this stty raw solution would work.

Comment: All characters between `00` and `1F` have shortcuts. Answer updated.

Comment: This is SO CLOSE that it's frustrating, because like I said I can't pipe input or IO redirect it because when it looks for more user input it looks to that source and sees no interactive input and closes (at least I think that's what's happening). So everything would work except 84.